# Can anyone explain this type of matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication

[image: Please go through this example]

The problem I am facing is how to determine the column and the row of the resultant matrix.

Comment: I think it's `XOR Matrix Multiplication` , google it

Comment: It's not a real matrix multiplication that I'm aware of - it's an operator that was made up for your homework. The logic for how it works seems pretty obvious from the example given. `A (x) B` is `[[A * b_0,0; A * b_1,0], [A * b_0,1; A * b_1,1]]`.